# Create a unique GUID on Each Record of existing data in the table

Tags: mysql

options like

UPDATE my_table set guid_field = (SELECT UUID());

just updates all records as the same GUID

Comment: Your update statement works correctly see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d071bea32751f408264a9f494d2637d2

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer that updates all records with a new GUID on each record.

```
select @i:=uuid();

update my_table set guid_field = (@i:=uuid());
```

Comment: what about `update my_table set guid_field = (select uuid());` ?

Comment: No that does not work as all GUIDs on that table is the same and not different per record